# Do something before and after route changes using react-router-dom v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create a special in-between-pages transition, I already tried with `react-transition-group` but it does not do exactly what I need.

This is the current approach I have using jQuery:

[image: Current approach]

That solution uses JS to check when a link without "no-loader" class is clicked and, if the clicked link doesn't has that class, it prevents the default `a` tag behaviour, applies the `in` class to the `loader` element and then uses `window.location.href` to redirect.

```
//jQuery
$("a:not('.no-loader')").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    var link_href = $(this).attr("href");

    if (link_href == "#") {
      return;
    }

    if (link_href !== window.location.href && link_href+"/" !== window.location.href) {
      $loader.addClass("in").promise().done(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
          window.location.href = link_href;
        }, 1050);
      });
    }
  });
```

Now that I am using -and learning- React, I can't find the way to create the *before-mount* and *after-mount* transition (just apply a CSS class to the "loader" HTML element but imagine *any other thing inside a JS function*) using `BrowserRouter` and `Routes`.

Is there any way to get callback functions on RRD or should I use other package for this?

Comment: You may be able to use [getUserConfirmation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/getuserconfirmation-func) as the "before" hook but there doesn't seem to be a function for after. Your best bet is probably registering a custom listener directly on the [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history), alternatively you could make use of the React component lifecyle hooks e.g. `componentDidMount` / `componentDidUnmount`

Comment: @James I tried with `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUnmount` but both hooks are triggered and I cannot delay them, apply the CSS class and then make the hook continue. I'll check about the history listener.

Comment: are you just looking for a way to have a transition out and then into the next view? Couldn't you use the `getUserConfirmation` event to trigger the "close" animation and `componentDidMount` for the "open" animation?